# How to add extensions to whitelist on firefox GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, firefox

So I have tried all of the things that I could think of, I have used the suggested json that firefox have on their git hub found here: 
https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/v1.9_release/README.md#extensionsettings

I have tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOX0D.png) which is nearly the same as it is given in the document above, this did not work at stopping everything apart from uBlock form being installed. [Policy on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs91p.png) [Ghostery being installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndt1U.png) These two images are taken with in two minutes so the policy is applied when installing ghostery.

I have also tried to make it so that the specific addon is set to be able to download through the allowed sites setting. [GPO Allowed sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z6uo.png) This did not work showing the error. [Policy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqrvo.png) You would assume that just having this would mean that you would not be able to install addons but I am able to install any addon.

I am not able to find anything apart from things about policypak. Which is completly usless to me.

If you have any suggestions or ideas please let me know.

Comment: Specifically enumerating the things you have tried may be helpful.  As well as including any errors that you received when actually using the recommended method.  (That is, the screenshots of errors encountered when attempting to achieve this by an allowed sites workaround is really less helpful than including screenshots or errors from when you were trying this the correct way); I would update your question to include some of that information.

Comment: unfortunatley it is not possible to take screenshots of anymore errors to do with allowed sites as the only error that I could find was the one in the screenshot. But i have added more information overall that goes a bit more in depth.